# Testing custom salesforce plugin

Tags: unit-test, salesforcedx-cli, sfdx-plugin

I am currently trying to test a custom salesforce plugin which deploys a payload to a specific org. The plugin itself is coded in typescript and the unit tests are using mocha/chai.

I am running into a few issues mostly around mocking an alias.  Currently, when I test the plugin command it states I need to use a registered alias. My question is is there a way to use a 'fake' alias?

Test code:

```
    it('returns success when deploy is called', async () => {

  sinon.stub(LSAppApi as any, 'predeploySf').callsFake( (_lspath, _buildFilesPath) => {} );

  sinon.stub( fs, 'readFileSync' ).returns('<html></html>');
//  sinon.stub(LSAppApi as any, 'execCmd');
  sinon.spy( LSAppApi as any, 'deployLSApp' ).apply(LSAppApi, ["some/path", "my-hub-org"]);

  const res = LSAppDeploy.prototype.deploy( `some/path` );


  console.log(res.error);
  expect(res.status).to.equal( 200 );
  expect(res.error).to.not.exist;
  expect(res.message).to.equal( 'Deploy successful.' );
});
```

The plugin command I am testing:

```
    public static deployLSApp(localPath: string, alias: string) {
    console.log( '\n:> Starting deploy of S&E components...'.cyan );

    return this.execCmd(`sfdx force:source:deploy -m "ApexPage:somePage,  StaticResource:someResource" -u ${ alias }`, localPath );
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate word "fake"? Do you want to test that it has been actually deployed or do you want to test behaviour if there is failed/success response?

Comment: We are trying to test that the command itself works without actually running the command.

Comment: Now I can not follow that. How it that possible to check if something runs without running it?